# What is the best method of capturing the power query name as a custom column in Excel power query?

Tags: excel

Is there a function in Excel 365 Power Query that I can use to capture the name of the power query as a custom column?  I am loading many excel files by creating a query for each file.  When I append the queries into one query, I would like to have a custom column that contains the name of the original query from which the dataset came from.